# How do I get my OpenidController working in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error:

> uninitialized constant OpenidsController

I can't figure out why. I'm following this guide: http://www.danwebb.net/2007/2/27/the-no-shit-guide-to-supporting-openid-in-your-applications

I used the following command to generate the controller:

```
script/generate controller Openid new create complete
```

And I have put the following line in my routes file as the guide says to do:

```
map.resource :openid, :member => { :complete => :get }
```

Any ideas? I'm new to RoR so hopefully this is easy for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change your route to this

```
map.resource :openid, :member => { :complete => :get }, :controller => 'openid'
```

or rename your controller class to OpenidsController.

One thing to take note of is that blog post is nearly 3 years old - you might want to consider other articles as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to find something that's more recent... there just doesn't seem to be information out there that's as up to date as the stuff we have in the .net world... guess that's to be expected though

Comment: There's a lot of out there, like .net has it's own "in" set of tools, so does Rails. For example I'd say the current standard in Rails for authorization is Authlogic at the moment, but if you aren't searching for the term Authlogic in google, you're probably not going to find it. A good way of keeping on the pulse of Rails is the Rails Envy podcast and the Railscasts screencasts. A couple of links: http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic  http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [OpenID example](http://github.com/stympy/openid-rails-kit) helpful, though it's also a little dated at this point.