# How do I use open id in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

There doesn't appear to be any recent information about using Open ID in Ruby on Rails... the only walkthroughs that I can find do not work anymore. Does anyone know of a walkthrough or documentation that will actually work with modern versions of ruby on rails and required software?

I've been struggling with this for days and cannot make anything work.

Comment: I recommended Authlogic on one of my previous comments - were you not able to get it working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776851/how-do-i-get-my-openidcontroller-working-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

This screencast is well done and fairly recent (july 2009):

[Railscast on openid with authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic)

Answer (score 0):

I found the early [OpenID Railscast (68)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication) really useful when I implemented OpenID, as well as [Dan Webb's guide](http://www.danwebb.net/2007/2/27/the-no-shit-guide-to-supporting-openid-in-your-applications).